# Commutating nilpotent operators

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, nilpotence

Is there good examples of collection of nilpotent operators that commute with themselves?

Is there a good reference for a collection commutative nilpotent operators that commute with themselves or commutative zero divisors?

---

Specifically for large enough $m\in\Bbb N$ I am looking for $t=\alpha m$ for some fixed $\alpha>0$ matrices $A_1,\dots,A_t$ that are commutative ( $\forall i,j\in\{1,\dots,t\}$ $A_iA_j=A_jA_i$ holds) and satisfy one of following two:

> > **(1)** For any $i\in\{1,\dots,t\}$ $A_i^2=0$. What is smallest size of matrices (can they be $\beta m\times\beta m$ for some fixed $\beta>0$)?
> >
> > **(2)** $\forall i_1,i_2,i_3,\dots\in\{1,\dots,t\}$ we have $Tr(A_{i_1}A_{i_2}A_{i_3}\dots)\neq0\iff {i_1}\neq {i_2}\wedge {i_2}\neq {i_3}\wedge {i_3}\neq {i_1}\dots$ holds. Can matrices also be of size $\beta m\times\beta m$ for some fixed $\beta>0$?

Comment: Commutative with what ? Among themselves or with other operators?

Comment: With other operators.

Comment: Look inside some commutative ring, for example $k[x]/(x^n)$, or $k[x,y] / (xy)$. Your question is *very* broad. Maybe you can ask for something more specific? (Put more conditions on your operators.)

Comment: The only operators that are commutative with *all* other operators are the scalar ones, and the only scalar nilpotent operators is the zero one.

Comment: I am looking for matrix examples.

Comment: @Joanpemo not all operators but I just need a finite collection.

Comment: @Student. Change in my past comment matrix for operators: it remains valid.

Comment: Maybe you are looking to learn about representations of Abelian groups? Oh, never mind. You said nilpotent.

Comment: @Student. But then this could easily depend on the the finite collection of operators...

Comment: Could it be that you mean "commuting nilpotent operators" ?

Comment: $A B = BA$ with $A^n = 0$ and $B^k = 0$, but he also wrote that $n=k=2$

Comment: @user1952009 more complicated than that even Trace constraint is enough.

Comment: @Student. Unfortunately a "commutative operator (or matrix)" does not exist. So what exactly do you mean with a commutative matrix ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde the first interesting question I see is : for a nilpotent operator $A$, what is the set of nilpotent operators which commute with $A$ ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. That $O(m)$ thing is confusing. Anyway, the thread [How many commuting nilpotent matrices are there?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39252/how-many-commuting-nilpotent-matrices-are-there) on MO may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a theorem that is relevant to your question: A Lie sub algebra of $End(V)$ (V finite dimensional) consisting of nilpotent operators is simultaneously strictly upper triangularizable. I mean that you can pick a basis so that they all are zero on and below the diagonal. (This is Engels theorem. A nice reference is Serre's Lie algebras and Lie groups.)

(The condition on commutativity means that these form a Lie sub algebra.)

I'm still a little confused about what specifically you are asking, but you can probably play around with this a bit to produce a result.

Concrete translation of a specific case:

Let $A_i$ be a collection of commuting, nilpotent operators on a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Then there is a basis $v_i$ for $V$ in which each $A_i$ is represented by a strictly upper triangular matrix.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The lie algebra generated by them contains a diagonal matrix, which is not nilpotent. What I mean is that all of the operators in the Lie algebra are nilpotent.

Comment: No, he means Engel's theorem, and yes, this assumption is sufficient ; your counterexample is incorrect because the Lie subalgebra generated by nilpotent elements will not in general consist in nilpotent element (and he did specify that all the elements of the Lie subalgebra should be nilpotent, which always happens if it is generated by *commuting* nilpotent elements).

Comment: @AreaMan Could you be more explicit and matrix theoretic since I am looking for concrete examples?

Comment: when you say the Lie algebra generated by $(A_i)_{i \in \{1 \ldots t\}}$ where $A_i A_j = A_j A_i$, you mean matrices of the form $\sum_{i=1}^t c_i A_i$ and that's all ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Three_dimensions

Comment: @AreaMan Yes, you are right. Serre has this result under the name "Engel". Usually Engel's theorem is that a Lie algebra is nilpotent if and only if all adjoint operators are nilpotent.

Comment: @Student. Yes, I updated it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see, thanks!

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, in this case. The lie algebra generated by S = the smallest Lie algebra containing S.